# D3 Gradient starting point

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have this circual chart - https://jsfiddle.net/kyleopperman/aacgzxed/ - but i am struggling to get the gradient to start in the center of each segment and fill out to the edge. Can anyone help me with this?

```
var gradient = vis.append("defs")
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "gradient")
  .attr("x1", "0%")
  .attr("y1", "0%")
  .attr("x2", "100%")
  .attr("y2", "100%")
  .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

gradient.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "0%")
  .attr("stop-color", "#61B5C3")
  .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

gradient.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "100%")
  .attr("stop-color", "#5393AC")
  .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
```

Comment: Don't you want a radial gradient?

Comment: I've tested with a radial too, i suppose the problem is that each of cx, and cy co-ordinates need to be dynamic based on the position of the segment. So I guess a factory function is needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I've managed to figure this one out using a radialGradient

```
var radialGradient = vis.append("defs")
    .append("radialGradient")
    .attr("id", "radialGradient")
    .attr("cx", "0%")
    .attr("cy", "0%")
    .attr("r", "50%")
    .attr("fx", "0%")
    .attr("fy", "0%")
    .attr("spreadMethod", "pad")
    .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
```

Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kyleopperman/aacgzxed/1/

Comment: You can accept your own answer, SO allows it (after some hours).